# Write to an address stored in a register

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

This is what I want to do:

I want to write to an address stored in a register so I can use it in this way;

```
mov bx, STRING
add bx, 0x1

;and here I want to write a value the the address in bx

STRING: db "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I could understand that there might be a simple instruction for this but I can't find it.

I am on a 16-bit processor with the NASM assembler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to refer to the memory located at the address contained in register `bx` is `[bx]`. So if you want to take the value contained in another register and store it at `[bx]` you would use:

```
mov [bx],al
mov [bx],dx
mov [bx],ecx
; ..etc..
```

You can also store an immediate value directly:

```
mov byte [bx],0
mov byte [bx],'A'
mov word [bx],0x1234
; ..etc..
```

Note the size prefix (`byte`, `word`, etc) which is used to tell the assembler what size the immediate operand should be. This is necessary when writing immediates directly to memory, since just writing something like `mov [bx],0` would be ambiguous.

Comment: Additional info: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/fall2001/books/labmanual/inst-ref-mov.html and https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/fall2001/books/labmanual/inst-ref.html#INST-REF-OPERAND-SPEC